# what error is in my code, it doesn't work as intended

Tags: python-3.x

so my code run and there is no error it's just that it doesn't do what i coded it to do, it doesn't ask for "option" variable and skips the for loop and the "num_of_details" variable, can someone explain what is wrong?

```
def menu():
option = input("1 = Enter and store student details")    
if option == 1:
    num_of_details = int("How many student detail's do you wnat to add?")
    database = open("database.txt","r+")
    for i in range(num_of_details):
        student_details()
        database.write([surname,forename,date_of_birth,home_address,home_phone_number,gender,unique_ID_number,school_email])      
menu()
```

Comment: If your code on your computer matches the indentation of the code as you've pasted it into the question, that should create an error, but maybe the code just didn't paste correctly into the question here. Is your python version really python `3.x`? If so, you should *at least* see the prompt for "option", but since you don't see the "option" prompt that could be an issue with proper code indentation.

Comment: for the comparision `if option == 1:` to work, you'll need to cast the option from string to an `int` first, then compare, something like: `option = int(raw_input("1 = Enter and store student details"))`. also, you need to use `input()` to get the use input for "How many student details ...?", before cast it to `int()`, so same as before: `num_of_details = int(input("How many student detail's do you wnat to add?"))`